# How do I write to shared memory using a char pointer?

Tags: c++, semaphore, shared-memory

```
#define MIN_PID 300
#define MAX_PID 5000
#define SPROD_NAME "/sem_prod"
#define SCONS_NAME "/sem_cons"

std::vector<int> pidb = {};
int count = 0;

char* pid_manager::produce(pid_manager& task_manager, char *ptr) {
    const char* pid = (std::to_string(task_manager.allocate_pid())).c_str();
    std::cout << "Produced: " << pid << std::endl;
    std::strcpy(ptr, pid);
    ptr += strlen(pid);
    count += strlen(pid);
    std::cout << ptr <<std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

char* pid_manager::consume(pid_manager& task_manager, char *ptr) {
    std::cout << "Consumed: " << std::endl;
    const char* data = ptr;
    std::cout << data << std::endl;
    return ptr;
}

void pid_manager::producer(pid_manager& task_manager) {

    // connecting to shared semaphores
    sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SPROD_NAME, 0);
    sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SCONS_NAME, 0);

    // shared memory arguments, and creation/configuration of shared memory using mmap
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    const char *name = "OS";
    int fd;
    char *ptr;
    fd = shm_open(name,O_CREAT | O_RDWR,0666);
    ftruncate(fd, SIZE);
    ptr = (char *)mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

    // creating PID map
    task_manager.allocate_map();

    // signals to consumer to connect to memory
    sem_post(sem_cons);

    sem_wait(sem_prod);
    ptr = task_manager.produce(task_manager, ptr);
    sem_post(sem_cons);
}

void pid_manager::consumer(pid_manager& task_manager) {

    // connecting to shared semaphores
    sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SPROD_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
    sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SCONS_NAME, O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

    // shared memory arguments and mapping consumers ptr to shared memory
    const int SIZE = 4096;
    const char *name = "OS";
    int fd;
    char *ptr;
    fd = shm_open(name, O_RDONLY, 0666);
    ptr = (char *)mmap(0, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
    std::cout << ptr << std::endl;

    // munmap(ptr,SIZE);
    // close(fd);
    // return;

    // sending signal to producer that consumer is connected to shared memory
    sem_post(sem_prod);

    // waits for memory to be written, then reads the memory
    sem_wait(sem_cons);
    std::cout << "Running consume" << std::endl;
    ptr = task_manager.consume(task_manager, ptr);
    sem_post(sem_prod);


    //remove shared memory
    shm_unlink(name);
}


int main(){
    // initialization of name of process, pid_manager object, and shared memory semaphores
    std::string name;
    pid_manager task_manager;
    sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SPROD_NAME, O_CREAT, 0666, 1);
    sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SCONS_NAME, O_CREAT, 0666, 0);

    if (fork() == 0) {
        name = "producer";
        sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SPROD_NAME, 0);
        sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SCONS_NAME, 0);
    }
    else {
        name = "parent";
        if (fork() == 0) {
            name = "consumer";
            sem_t *sem_prod = sem_open(SPROD_NAME, 0);
            sem_t *sem_cons = sem_open(SCONS_NAME, 0);
        }
    }
    
    // sem_unlink(SPROD_NAME);
    // sem_unlink(SCONS_NAME);
    // sem_close(sem_prod);
    // sem_close(sem_cons);
    // return 0;

    // runs producer process if not parent
    if (name == "producer") {
        sem_wait(sem_prod);
        std::cout << "Producer Process Executed" << std::endl;
        task_manager.producer(std::ref(task_manager));
    }

    //runs consumer process if not parent
    if (name == "consumer") {
        sem_wait(sem_cons);
        std::cout << "Consumer Process Executed" << std::endl;
        task_manager.consumer(std::ref(task_manager));
    }

    std::cout << "Parent process here!" << std::endl;
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    
    sem_close(sem_prod);
    sem_close(sem_cons);
    return 0;
}
```

In my code the producer function creates shared memory, the consumer function connects to that shared memory, and they access it through individual const char* ptr's. Producer and Consumer both call to produce and consume which are supposed to do the actual reading and writing, but both freeze on the line they write and read on with no error or termination.

All calls to pid related stuff is just the project we're building off of which is just an array and the functions return the index of the array they allocate/destroy.
I am inexperienced with shared memory/semaphores so I just clear the memory by commenting code in and running it since I cant get it to run till the end.

I apologize for the large block of bad code, but I really cant figure out how to make it work.

I've mainly focused on trying to get the produce function to write to the memory where ptr is pointed because consume cant even run without produce running first. My teacher's example is:

```
const char* pid = (std::to_string(task_manager.allocate_pid())).c_str();
sprintf(ptr, "%s", pid);
```

but I've also tried:

```
const char* pid = (std::to_string(task_manager.allocate_pid())).c_str();
std::strcpy(ptr, pid);
```

Comment: `const char* pid = (std::to_string(task_manager.allocate_pid())).c_str();` This constructs a temporary `std::string` object, then grabs a pointer to the memory block managed by that object. Then the temporary is destroyed at the semicolon, and the pointer becomes dangling. The subsequent attempt to use this pointer exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.